# How to modify genre info in Android

Tags: android

All

I want to modify song's genre data,but I don't know how to do it.I don't know how to get a table with audio'id and genre's id.I can get genres's id from Audio.Genre and get audios'id from Audio.Genre.Members.

I get /data/data/com.android.providor.media/databases/external-e5bd14fb.db file with adb shell.In this db file,I find a audio_genre_map table.In this table,I find 3 columns _id,audio_id,genre_id.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the ide3 tags. Look at http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/

Comment: As I know , we can not modify it using Android provider . Thanks a lot.Do your means modify mp3 file . Maybe it is  the only solution.But for my project , it cannot allow to modify mp3 file . So as result,we did not modify the genre metadata.Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively you could create your own database with your "own modification" which then refer to the unmodified mp3 files. Duplicates would then get the same modification but so be it.